# Why doesn't "myValue = myArray[1.5];" return error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compiler-errors

In order to grab an item from an array, the value to grab an item must be an integer. Like this:

```
var myArray = ["apples", "oranges", "sugar", "onions", "steak"];
alert(myArray[2]);//2 is the integer I'm talking about
```

However, the following code also is still functional.

```
var myArray = ["apples", "oranges", "sugar", "onions", "steak"];
alert(myArray[1.5]);//1.5 is the decimal(float) value I'm talking about
```

Why doesn't the system automatically round the value? Or at least give out an error when it is a decimal? The following code returns no error whatsoever:

```js
try {
var myArray = ["apples", "oranges", "sugar", "onions", "steak"];
var healthy = myArray[1.5];
} catch (e) {alert(e);}
```

Why doesn't the system alert round the value to the nearest integer, or return an error?

Comment: arrays are objects and behave like objects. the use of number which is not a defined index of the array is just a plain value for accessing a property.

Comment: @NinaScholz But if you can't have a value in the array of position "1.5", then why shouldn't the system round the value, or return an error?

Comment: the problem is not having an array, but an object. the object allows to use more keys than an array would use them as item index (which has to be a positive 32 bit (integer) number) all other values, even neagive numbers or `1.5` are taken as string (as the indices) and taken as property accessor. these properties are kind of invisible by using array methods, but you could get them with object methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are objects (i.e. `typeof [] === 'object'`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description:

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations. [...]
>
> Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot be applied to these named properties.

As arrays are objects, you can add new properties to it:

```
var myArray = ["apples", "oranges", "sugar", "onions", "steak"];
myArray.foo = 'bar';
myArray[1.5] = 'baz';
```

Object properties are always strings. Now when you try to access `myArray[1.5]`, you are not accessing an array index but the property `myArray['1.5']` with the value `baz`.

Comment: What does `myArray.foo` do?

Comment: It gets or sets the array's object property with the name `foo`.